# Delete app which is waiting to be submitted in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to delete an app which is waiting to be submitted in iTunes connect.

Please let me know how can i do this?

Comment: A new version, or the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not delete app from app store in any condition. You can inactive once it gets **Active means Ready for sale** state, or make it inactive region/country wise.

Another way is move your app from one developer account to another one, this is also available once your app get Active status from Apple review team.

**Update 1**

Goto **iTunes** with your developer account,  **Select App** which You want to move, in Top Menu, there us last menu **More -> Transfer App**.

It requires some criteria to be fulfilled, if all of them gets fulfilled, then in bottom-right corder go with **Continue**.

In next screen you have to add 2 things of second developer.

1. Recipient's Team Agent Apple ID
2. Team ID

and Continue with that.

Comment: how can i move the app from one developer account to another one.

Comment: @user1010280, Please see **Update 1** from updated answer